# Sample configuration/properties xml file for SphinxTrain for Sphinx4

Tags: java, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, cmusphinx, sphinx4

I am using Sphinx4. I am trying to train accoustic model using SphinxTrain. I have audio samples and transcript file.

As **Trainer.java** expects configuration file (containing filepath for audio samples and transcript files.) I found sample trainer.properties file for this configuration. But I have SphinxTrain project with Sphinx4 which expects trainer.xml file. For which i need sample format.

Below is sample trainer.properties file which i need in xml format.

```
############################################################
#
# Trainer properties
#
############################################################

# File containing list of audio files
edu.cmu.sphinx.trainer.ControlFile.audioFile '' train.ctl

# File containing list of transcriptions, parallel to the audio file list
edu.cmu.sphinx.trainer.ControlFile.transcriptFile '' train.trans

# Initial stage to be done, defaults to _00_INITIALIZATION
edu.cmu.sphinx.trainer.Trainer.initialStage '' _00_INITIALIZATION

# Final stage to be done, defaults to _40_TIED_CD_TRAIN
edu.cmu.sphinx.trainer.Trainer.finalStage '' _10_CI_TRAIN

# Controls the maximum number of BW iterations
edu.cmu.sphinx.trainer.Trainer.maximumIteration '' 10

# Controls the minimum relative change in log likelihood to be considered as "stable"
edu.cmu.sphinx.trainer.Trainer.minimumImprovement '' 0.2

############################################################
#
# Acoustic model properties
#
############################################################

# These are the same as the decoder

edu.cmu.sphinx.knowledge.acoustic.location file:////data/model

# But these are pertinent only to the trainer. They refer to where the models will be saved

############################################################
# 
# FrontEnd properties, same as in the decoder
#
############################################################

############################################################
# 
# Dictionary properties, same as in the decoder
#
############################################################
```

I would really appreciate if anyone can provide with sample configuration.xml for SphinxTrain for Sphinx4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sphinx4 is irrelevant here.

Sphinxtrain documentation is available on website

http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/wiki/tutorialam

You just need to follow it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but can you explain your statement "Sphinx4 is irrelevant here."  ? if you will see code of sphinx4 than you will find package named as "Trainer" and there is one call named Trainer that will do all stuff. would really appreciate if you will correct me if  i am wrong.

Comment: This code is experimental and does not work. If you want to train the model you need to use the process described in documentation.